# Can't highlight ngx-bootstrap datepicker month

Tags: html, css, angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to highlight selected month using ngx-bootstrap with min-mode.

In datepicker we can highlight like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd8kM.jpg).

In a same manner I want to highlight in ngx-bootstrap [Ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR8kq.jpg)

I have tried a lot to highlight selected month but nothing seems working.

```
export class AppComponent  {
    bsValue: Date = new Date(2017, 7);
    minMode: BsDatepickerViewMode = 'month';
    bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, {
      minMode : this.minMode
    });
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<bs-datepicker-inline [bsConfig]="bsConfig" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue"></bs-datepicker-inline>
```

[stackblitz editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcbl4o)

I feel it's something fairly simple with config.

Comment: Have you found any solutions for this problem, cause i have it as well and nothing works... :(

Comment: @ExariConstantin Please check my comment on [github](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5166#issuecomment-508733952)